# using NSXMLparser, how do you parse an xml file which has same name tags but in different elements?

Tags: ios, xml, nsxmlparser

Is it possible to give path expressions in NSXMLparser? I have an XML file which has a few same name tags, but they are in different element. Is there any way to differentiate between them. Here is the XML:

```
<Schools>
        <School>
            <ID>335823</ID> 
            <Name>Fairfax High School</Name> 
            <Student>
                <ID>4195653</ID>
                <Name>Will Turner</Name>
            </Student>
            <Student>
                <ID>4195654</ID>
                <Name>Bruce Paltrow</Name>
            </Student>
            <Student>
                <ID>4195655</ID>
                <Name>Santosh Gowswami</Name>
            </Student>
        </School>
    <Schools>
```

Comment: Your XML is also missing the `/` on the final closing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create separate `School` and `Student` objects.  Your parser will have properties for `currentSchool` and `currentStudent`.  Whenever your parser hits the `<Student>` tag, call

```
self.currentStudent = [[MyStudentObject alloc] init];
```

Whenever your parser hits the `</Student>` tag, call

```
self.currentStudent = nil;
```

Then, when you hit the `<name>` tag, you can check to see if you have a `currentStudent`.  If you do, then the name is the name of that student.  If there is no current student, then the name is the name of the school.

```
if (self.currentStudent)
{
    self.currentStudent.name = /*string between <name> tags*/
}
else
{
    self.currentSchool.name = /*string between <name> tags*/
}
```

Sorry my code pieces are so brief, I don't have much time to type this now.  If more detail is needed, I can add more code later.

---

UPDATE

The quickest way for me to go into more detail is just to show the code for what I'm looking for, and put the comments explaining everything into the code.  If there are any questions on any part of this, or if anything needs to be explained further, let me know what to elaborate on and I'll do my best.

StudentXML.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface StudentXML : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ID;     // MAKE SURE THIS EXACTLY MATCHES THE ELEMENT IN THE XML!!
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Name;   // MAKE SURE THIS EXACTLY MATCHES THE ELEMENT IN THE XML!!

@end
```

StudentXML.m

```
#import "StudentXML.h"

@implementation StudentXML

@end
```

SchoolXML.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "StudentXML.h"

@interface SchoolXML : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *ID;     // MAKE SURE THIS EXACTLY MATCHES THE ELEMENT IN THE XML!!
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Name;   // MAKE SURE THIS EXACTLY MATCHES THE ELEMENT IN THE XML!!
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *studentsArray; // Array of StudentXML objects

@end
```

SchoolXML.m

```
#import "SchoolXML.h"

@implementation SchoolXML

// Need to overwrite init method so that array is created when new SchoolXML object is created
- (SchoolXML *) init;
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.studentsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        return self;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Error - SchoolXML object could not be initialized in init on SchoolXML.m");
        return nil;
    }
}

@end
```

SchoolsParser.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "SchoolXML.h"
#import "StudentXML.h"

@interface SchoolsParser : NSObject
{
    NSMutableString *currentElementValue;   // Will hold the string between tags until we decide where to put it
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) SchoolXML *currentSchool;     // Will hold the school that is in the process of being filled
@property (nonatomic, strong) StudentXML *currentStudent;   // Will hold the student that is in the process of being filled
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allSchools;   // This is the final list of all the data in the XML file

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string;
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName;

@end
```

SchoolsParser.m

```
#import "SchoolsParser.h"

@implementation SchoolsParser

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
// This method will be hit each time the parser sees an opening tag
// elementName is the string between the <> (example "School")
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"School"])
    {
        self.currentSchool = [[SchoolXML alloc] init];
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Student"])
    {
        self.currentStudent = [[StudentXML alloc] init];
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
// This method will be hit each time the parser sees a string between tags
// string is the value between the open and close tag (example "Fairfax High School")
// We take string and hold onto it until we can decide where it should be put
{
    currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
// This method will be hit each time the parser sees an closing tag
// elementName is the string between the </> (example "School")
// This is the method where we decide where we want to put the currentElementValue string
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Student"])
    {
        // Put the current student into the studentsArray of the currentSchool
        [self.currentSchool.studentsArray addObject:self.currentStudent];

        // We've finished building this student and have put it into the school we wanted, so we clear out currentStudent so we can reuse it next time
        self.currentStudent = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"School"])
    {
        // Put the current school into the allSchoolsArray to send back to our view controller
        [self.allSchools addObject:self.currentSchool];

        // We've finished building this school and have put it into the return array, so we clear out currentSchool so we can reuse it next time
        self.currentSchool = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"Schools"])
    {
        // We reached the end of the XML document
        return;
    }
    else
    // This is either a Name or an ID, so we want to put it into the correct currentSomething we are building
    {
        if (self.currentStudent)
        // There is a currentStudent, so the Name or ID we found is that of a student
        {
            // Since the properties of our currentStudent object exactly match the elementNames in our XML, the parser can automatically fills values in where they need to be without us doing any more
            // For example, it will take "Will Turner" in the <Name> tags in the XML and put it into the .Name property of our student
            [self.currentStudent setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
        }
        else
        // There was no student, so the Name or ID we found is that of a school
        {
            // Since the properties of our currentStudent object exactly match the elementNames in our XML, the parser can automatically fills values in where they need to be without us doing any more
            // For example, it will take "Fairfax High School" in the <Name> tags in the XML and put it into the .Name property of our school
            [self.currentSchool setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];
        }
    }

    // We've now put the string in currentElementValue where we wanted it, so we clear out currentElementValue so we can reuse it next time
    currentElementValue = nil;
}

-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError
{
    NSLog(@"Error in SchoolsParser.m");
    NSLog(@"%@",parseError.description);
}

@end
```

UIViewController.m where you want to start parsing (make sure you `#include` SchoolXML, StudentXML, and SchoolsParser):

```
- (void) startSchoolParser
{
    NSXMLParser *nsXmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:responseData]; // where "responseData" is the NSData object that holds your XML
    SchoolsParser *parser = [[SchoolsParser alloc] init];
    [nsXmlParser setDelegate:parser];
    if ([nsXmlParser parse])
    {
        // Parsing was successful
        NSArray *allSchools = parser.allSchools;
        // You can now loop through allSchools and use the data how ever you want

        // For example, this code just NSLog's all the data
        for (SchoolXML *school in allSchools)
        {
            NSLog(@"School Name = %@",school.Name);
            NSLog(@"School ID = %@",school.ID);
            for (StudentXML *student in school.studentsArray)
            {
                NSLog(@"Student Name = %@",student.Name);
                NSLog(@"Student ID = %@",student.ID);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Parsing Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, more detail, because i did not understand how can i add all element in a single NSDictionnary.

Comment: @user2299789: You can nest NSDictionaries inside of one another, so you can always end up with one final NSDictionary that holds everything, if that is what you need.  Can you update your question with the code in your parser's .m file?  I want to see how you're using the parser delegate methods.

Comment: yes that's my Question, but until now i did not write parser's. file because, i did not found solution.

Answer (score 1):

1) Initialize an array when parser encounters School tag, this array will hold all Student objects that you are going to create.

2) Create Student object everytime you see Student start tag.

3) Then parser encounters ID tag parse it into [studentObj setId:parsedContent]

4) then parser encounters Name tag [studentObj setName:parsedContent]

5) Now parser encounters end of student tag , now add this studentObj to array that you initialized in step 1

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to just have two `BOOL` class property/ivars, one for schools and one for students. Then in `didStartElement`, if the `elementName` is `@"School"` or `@"Student"`, then set the appropriate boolean property/ivar. Likewise, in `didEndElement`, if the `elementName` is `@"School"` or `@"Student"`, then clear the appropriate boolean property/ivar. Then, when parsing `@"Name"`, you can check those two boolean properties/ivars to see which one you're parsing and take the appropriate steps. (For example, if the student boolean is true, then clearly the name is a student. If the student boolean is false, but the school boolean is true, then the name is that of a school.)

There are more elegant ways of solving the problem (e.g. [XML Node Parser](https://github.com/robertmryan/xml-node-parser)), but this is probably simplest.

---

By the way, I don't know if you have any say over the structure of the XML, but I think it's best if all arrays were wrapped inside their own element. Thus instead of:

```
<Schools>
    <School>
        <ID>335823</ID>
        <Name>Fairfax High School</Name>
        <Student>
            <ID>4195653</ID>
            <Name>Will Turner</Name>
        </Student>
        <Student>
            <ID>4195654</ID>
            <Name>Bruce Paltrow</Name>
        </Student>
        <Student>
            <ID>4195655</ID>
            <Name>Santosh Gowswami</Name>
        </Student>
    </School>
<Schools>
```

I would have preferred to see a "Students" element name wrapping the list of students. Your final closing `Schools` tag is also missing the `/`.

```
<Schools>
    <School>
        <ID>335823</ID>
        <Name>Fairfax High School</Name>
        <Students>
            <Student>
                <ID>4195653</ID>
                <Name>Will Turner</Name>
            </Student>
            <Student>
                <ID>4195654</ID>
                <Name>Bruce Paltrow</Name>
            </Student>
            <Student>
                <ID>4195655</ID>
                <Name>Santosh Gowswami</Name>
            </Student>
        </Students>
    </School>
</Schools>
```

You can write a parser that handles the former, but when you get into a world of more dynamically generated results, it's useful to have the XML more accurately reflect the structure of the underlying data. I know that as you're writing a very specific parser for this one XML feed it probably seems irrelevant, but it really is a more logical structure.

Comment: yes and with this methode, i can add all elemebt in one NSDictionnary?

Comment: With this setup, you'd really only need 1 `BOOL`, for the student, right?  With the assumption that if the name isn't the name of a student, it must be the name of a school.

Comment: @GeneralMike - Obviously, yes, you only need one boolean for this XML. (In fact, when you've got your structures for parsing and filling the nodes of your tree, you don't need any.) I was just trying to make it super obvious and super simple. And by having two booleans, you are a little more robust, able to detect malformed XML, able to handle if the `Schools` tag is later embedded in a `Districts` structure which has its own name (e.g. often people give us simplified renditions of their XML), etc.

Comment: @user2299789 - Yes you can. By the way, I've updated my answer with a suggestion on the refinement of your XML structure. It might not make a big deal now, but it is a little more logical (and if you ever write a parser that is dynamically parsing the results, you'll thank yourself for doing this).

Comment: @user2299789 I uploaded a sample project that bypasses your confusion over the `BOOL` and illustrates a parser that can parse an XML into a tree structure, that completely eliminates your question of "how do I make sure the `Name` element is attached to the right element (the school version the student)": https://github.com/robertmryan/xml-node-parser This may be too much for you to take in, but it parses an XML feed of arbitrary depth of nested tags into a single structure that you can then navigate. Your sample XML (or at least my rendition) is featured in the documentation.